# Where to store editable content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I am building a Rails app that is intended to be eventually used by non-technical people. It consists of a few pages with blocks of text and a special page with interactive canvas drawings.

I want to allow them to easily edit any piece of text contained in the application. What are the best ways to achieve that? Currently, text is written in the different views of the application, which does not allow them to edit it without having to connect via FTP or similar and search for the right file.

I am thinking of three solutions:

1. Store all blocks of text in the database. On each page, fetch the requires blocks and insert them before rendering. Build a page that lists all blocks in the database in editable areas with a save button.
2. Store all blocks of text in a json file. Create a model that can read the file and fetch the blocks required by the views. Build a page that lets you edit each block and save it in the file.
3. Create some kind of password-protected admin interface that fetches all file in the views directory, use regexp to find blocks of text and allow the users to edit each block and save.

From my point of view, all of my three solutions look pretty bad. It does not feel okay to do so many calls to the database? Store your entire website text in a file? Parse HTML with regexps?

What are the usual approaches used to solve this problem?

Comment: if you want to update the text than you have to put content in database or some other txt file . so when user change that you have to rewrite that file

Comment: Sounds like a normal CMS. Most CMS's store their data in a database. Why do you need many database calls? What do you consider many?

Comment: Why should it be bad to do 'so many' database calls? That's a rather common thing to do. Some of the pages on web sites I have written needed to do much more requests to get all the data needed (products, images, downloadable documents...) for rendering.

Comment: I was taught at school to do as few database calls as possible because they are an expensive resource. I've never ran metrics myself, so I assumed fetching dozens of different rows on each page load for each user seemed a bit too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a great book out there: [Crafting Rails 4 Applications](http://pragprog.com/book/jvrails2/crafting-rails-applications). Here's the [link](http://pragprog.com/titles/jvrails2/source_code) to source code from the book. You will find example in `templater` folder. Basically, you will be able to create custom templates based on the request parameters (just like Rails does).

**Update**. Here's a couple of links:

1. [Default views in Rails 3.0 with custom resolvers](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2011/04/default-views-in-rails-3-0-with-custom-resolvers/) by José Valim (author of the book, by the way).
2. [Implementing a Rails 3 View Resolver](http://jkfill.com/2011/03/11/implementing-a-rails-3-view-resolver/).

Also, here's 5 coins from me. Basically, it works like this. You need to define your own resolver and connect it to your ApplicationController (or any other controller you want):

```
class Resolver < ActionView::Resolver
  # some code here
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  append_view_path Resolver.new
end
```

During the rendering process, Rails will ask your controller's resolvers to provide a template (it will go through each of them, until it finds template or until there won't be any resolvers left). In order to provide template, your resolver needs a `find_templates` method:

```
def def find_templates(name, prefix, partial, details)
  # some processing here
end
```

So, based on this method parameters, you're going to provide some database records. But even if you have some kind of model already, Rails expects this method to return `ActionView::Template` instance. It can be initialized like this:

```
ActionView::Template.new(source, identifier, handler, details)
```

So, that's how your `find_templates` should look like:

```
def find_templates(name, prefix, partial, details)
  template = DatabaseTemplate.find... # your custom model for DB templates 
  ActionView::Template.new...         # initializing actual template
end
```

Both model and resolver in detail are presented in the book's source code (`templater/3_final/app/models/sql_template.rb`).

Comment: Would you have a link to a code sample or a free resource? Thanks for the book link regardless. I tried to look at the source code but it doesn't make a lot of sense without the explanations...

Comment: Thank you! It looks interesting, I'm going to research more and try it.

Answer (score 1):

I have done that a couple times with awesome user satisfaction by using this:
http://jejacks0n.github.io/mercury/

There is also a Railscast available which gives you a good overview and step by step instructions:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/296-mercury-editor

Hope it helps. It looks good and is easy to use for end users.

Comment: That is impressive from a user-experience point of view! Thank you very much for this answer.